# Adding array strings from String.xml into ArrayList

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist, adapter

I am defining array strings into String.xml. Then I am going to add them into ArrayList. But I got an empty list.

String.xml:

```
<array name="restaurant_names">
    <item >Tobaz</item>
    <item >Lozanna</item>
    <item >Vetameen</item>
    <item >Baharat</item>
</array>
```

Java class:

```
ArrayList<RestaurantObjects> restaurant;
String name;
String type;
restaurant = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0;i>=R.array.restaurant_names;i++) {
   name = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.restaurant_names)[i];
   type = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.restaurant_names)[i];
   restaurant.add(new RestaurantObjects(name, type));
}

restaurantList.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(this,restaurant));
```

I tried to do it without the loop and it works perfect. is there something wrong with the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey you initialize i as zero:
Therefore it will never be larger than the list_size.
i recommend to change:

`for(int i=0;i>=R.array.restaurant_names;i++)` 
which is always false, loop does not start

to

`for(int i=0;i <R.array.restaurant_names;i++)`

that should work. I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

`R.array.restaurant_names` is an integer(resource identified to be more technical) generated by android's `R.java` that is pointed at actual `R.array.restaurant_names` in XML. It by no means aims to be used as array size which you're trying to pull off here.

Better go with the old way.

```
String[] restaurant_names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.restaurant_names);
```

and use `restaurant_names.length` in for loop. That should work out for your purpose.

```
int resturantNameSize = restaurant_names.length; 
for(int i=0;i<resturantNameSize;i++) {
        name = restaurant_names[i];
        type = restaurant_names[i];
        restaurant.add(new RestaurantObjects(name, type));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
for(int i=0;i>=R.array.restaurant_names;i++) {
```

`R.array.restaurant_names` isn't the number of items of the array.